# Does a function exist that will take arguments of $0,1,2,3$ and map to only values $0$ and $1$.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

To be clear:

$0\rightarrow0$,

$1\rightarrow1$,

$2\rightarrow1$,

$3\rightarrow1$

I know how to achieve it programmatically, as it is quite simple, but is there a purely mathematical way?

### I have been pondering this for a few days, my basic understanding of set theory says it should be possible but I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

edit

Thanks to fleablood for the simple and easy to understand solution.

I was trying to create a way (for my own curiosity) to find whether a year is a leap year without using if statements.  It was an assignment but I was supposed to use IF statements for it. I just wondered if it can be done any other way.  I'm sure I will make use of Fermat's little theorem in future.

in python
return (year % 4) ** 4) % 5 - ((year % 100) ** 100) % 101 + ((year % 400) ** 400) % 401

Comment: $f : \{0,1,2,3\} \to \{0,1\}$ defined by $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if $x=0$, and} \\ 1 & \text{otherwise,}\end{cases}$$ *n'est-ce pas*?

Comment: You seem to have defined such a function.

Comment: To expand just a bit on the other comments: you are making the common mistake of confusing a *function* with the *expression* used to define it.

Comment: @dbx ... and the *expression* of a function does not have to be a single statement of a mathematical formula.  *Expressing* $f(0) = 0$ and $f(x) = 1$ if $x = 1,2,$ or $3$ is a perfectly *valid* expression.

Comment: "I was trying to create a way (for my own curiosity) to find whether a year is a leap year without using if statements"  Well in that case you should just to the a boolean function.  In php you could simply write $return !(x \% 4);$.  If $x\% 4 ==0$ this returns $1$ or true or $x\% 4 \ne 0$ it returns $0$ or false.

Comment: @fleablood I clearly said I did not want to use IF functions. You even copypasted it. I also clearly said I wanted a function to be able to directly return only 0,1 MATHEMATICALLY. I am using Python so I could do this a million different ways.  Why are you being so weird about this? You gave me the solution I was looking for - a purely mathematical way. Its computationally wasteful so I would be unlikely to use it in reality but I simply wondered if there was a way; unless you have a more efficient method, I think you should stop wasting your time here? Thanks for the help, it opened my eyes.

Answer (score 2):

Um;  yes.  the function:

$f(x) =\begin{cases} 0 & \text{if }x = 0 \\ 1 & \text{if } x\ne 0\end{cases}$

=====

$f(x) = x^4 \% 5$ where $\%$ is the remainder function will do it (it's Fermat's little theorem).  But you don't need it.

If you can *say* $f$ maps $0$ to $0$ and $1,2,3$ to $1$, then that *IS* a function.  You don't *need* to do anything else.

"In mathematics, a function is a relation between a set of inputs and a set of permissible outputs with the property that each input is related to exactly one output."

So the sentence: $f$ maps $0$ to $0$ and $1,2,3$ to $1$ satisfies *EVERYTHING* you need to define a function.

Having some mathematical *formula* is *NOT* a requirement.

Comment: Well I am coming here as a programmer.  Maybe you can understand why I call it a function.

Comment: @user8078864 but even programmatically, couldn't you just say if x=0, f(x)=0, else f(x)=1 (assuming x can only be 0, 1, 2, 3)

Comment: Thanks for the solution though!  I never realised I was looking for fermat's little theorem.  Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: "Well I am coming here as a programmer. Maybe you can understand why I call it a function."  Not really.  I'd think a programmer would realize you can define a function to give any output you'd want.  And a *function(int a){if (a != 0) return 1; else return 0}* should have been obvious to write.

Comment: Fermat's little theorem is only one way to go and not a very good one at that.  As for prime $p$ and $a \not \equiv 0 \mod p$ we know $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \mod p$, that just seemed an obvious solution.  Although not as obvious as $f(x) = 0$ if $x = 0$ and $f(x) =1$ if $x \ne 1$.

Comment: @fleablood to be clear i did want the EXPRESSION. I am a programmer. I do not need to deal with formal math lexicon and notation everyday so I used the wrong word and I wasn't sure how to state what I needed help with.  If I knew all this stuff I wouldn't be here, would I?

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=\big\arrowvert\mu(x+4)\big\arrowvert$ seems to work

Comment: Perhaps it would be good to say what $\mu$ is?

Comment: $\mu$ is the Möbius Function (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MoebiusFunction.html)

Comment: Well..... fine... but I think we are doing the OP a disservice in even attempting to answer the question.  The function he wants is simply $f(x) = 0; $ for $x = 0$ and $1; $ for $x \ne 0$.  That's it.  That *is* the function.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways depending on what you allow yourself to use. One easy way is to use the polynomial function $f(x) := 1 + (x-1)(x-2)(x-3)/6.$

Comment: aahh this is a more efficient solution computationally I think.  Thanks!